# How to create a simple Local SQL database & insert values into it using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database

How to create a simple Local SQL database & insert values into it using C#? can any one provide me a sample code or project link.. i googled a bit, i am not getting how to do..
if you can advice it would be great

Comment: By local do you mean **server-less** database? Like **embedded** or in a **file**? Something like **SQL Server Compact**? http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx

Comment: By local means, like simple sql file creation in hardisk and accessing data like that..

Comment: Then that's exactly what I suggested. You can work with the database directly in Visual Studio (create DB, tables, modify, ...) ;)

Comment: i want to do it programmatically using C# functions.. is there a way?

Comment: It is. Check out msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ec4st0e3.aspx a sample to create the DB is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.createdatabase.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating a Desktop application, you can create a local Sql server Ce (Compact edition) database.

When you install Visual C# 2008 Express, It will automatically install SQL Compact 3.5 on your box.

Here is an excellent Getting started tutorial on the topic:

http://dotnetperls.com/sqlce

Answer (score 2):

I would use [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/). It's simple and it doesn't need any kind of installation, the full database it's only a file.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server Compact is a great embedded database. It is also fully documented on MSDN, see [System.Data.SqlServerCe Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlServerCe.aspx).

You can easily create and modify databases programatically, see [SqlCeEngine.CreateDatabase Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.createdatabase.aspx).

You can download it on the [SQL Server Compact Download Page](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact-downloads.aspx).

Comment: Hey, CE for windows mobile right. SO can we use the same for desktop?

Comment: @LLL: CE as in SQL Server **C**ompact **E**dition, not Windows CE.

Comment: oh.. Jaroslav Jandek Thanks..i will have look at it once.. Thanks again